# Magento - move static block under product grid for both anchor and non anchor category page

Tags: php, magento, static, block, categories

I've been trying yo figure out how to bring static block to the bottom of product list.

I was able to achieve this by:

Replacing

```
<?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
<?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
```

to

```
<?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
<?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
```

on catalog/category/view.phtml file

But it only works when your "Is Anchor" set to No.

If layered navigation is enabled, at first, static block shows up on the bottom,
but when the filter is completed, this static block comes back to the top.

I have looked at

```
<label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
```

and

```
<label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
```

in catalog.xml file to see any differences but couldn't find any differences related to this specific static block.

I'd really appreciate if any one can help me on this!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone? I spent almost whole day searching on Google how. Closest thing I only found was similar question from other site with no right answer. I was hoping there must be any one could answer this here..